# row and column scan of a bitmap in android

Tags: android

I have a jpg image. First i want to convert it to bitmap so that i can get all pixels from my picture. Then i want to keep the pixels into a two dimensional array as row and column of a matrix. Then i want to search either row or column or both to match with a color.That means i want to find if a row(or a column whatever i want) of that 2D matrix contains RED color(for example). I tried something like this:

```
      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.laser);
  bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);          

  int[] pixels = new int[bmp.getHeight()*bmp.getWidth()];
  bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());

        for(int i =0; i<pixels.length;i++){       
       if(pixels[i]==0xffff0000)
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          }
```

Here i took pixels into an array(1D) and check if a red color is exist or not in that array. But it didn't find although red color exists in my pic. Here may be the array cant get pixels. But this is not what i want. What i want is to keep the pixels into a two dimensional array as row and column of a matrix. Then i want to search either row or column or both to match with a color.That means i want to find if a row(or a column whatever i want) of that 2D matrix contains RED color(for example) in android???

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition from

```
if(pixels[i]==0xffff0000)
```

to

```
if(pixels[i]==Color.RED)
```

All values in the pixels array are packed ints representing a 'Color'

Answer (score 0):

Actually bitmap itself has the information encoded as a two dimensional array. You can access the pixel information as follows,

```
// To get the pixel information at the co-ordinate x,y of the image
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

// If you want to get the red, green, blue color depth
int red = Color.red(pixel);
int green = Color.green(pixel);
int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
```